# Cannot generate odds ratios for a Logit

Tags: stata

In Stata I typed

`logit alcohol_related speed_limit age speeding`

but then the next command

`logistic alcohol_related speed_limit age speeding, odds`

produced the error:

`option odds not allowed r(198);`

and when I type

`logit alcohol_related speed_limit age speeding or`

I get the error message

`variable or not found r(111);`

Comment: It looks like in your second command you’re missing a comma before “or”…that should fix it

Comment: @braces is right, but it's the 3rd command

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error:

```
option odds not allowed r(198);
```

because the `logistic` command does not have an option `odds`!

You'll see this if you review the help (`help logistic`).

The help also states the answer to your question:

"logistic displays estimates as odds ratios"

so it seems that the command you are looking for is simply:

```
logistic alcohol_related speed_limit age speeding
```

without the `,odds`

Alternatively, as braces pointed out above, you could add a comma to your second `logit` command:

```
logit alcohol_related speed_limit age speeding, or
```

In general, if you think you typed an option, and Stata says that it can't find a variable with the name of the option that you typed, then you are probably missing a comma.